# Decorating MKPinAnnotation

Tags: ios, mkmapview, mapkit, mkpinannotationview

How can I use the MKPinAnnotation and add another graphic underneath it? I want to add direction arrows to the pin, not replace the pin with another graphic. Somebody have any ideas / links?

Answer (score 0):

MapKit API doesn't allow this. Try copying the default pin image using something like https://github.com/0xced/iOS-Artwork-Extractor and starting with that.